# AdMob Ad and ErrorCode cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have added this code to see the error if App fails to receive ads.

```
    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
 // Set AdListener
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode error) {
            System.err.println("Ad failed: " + ad.toString() + error.toString());    
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
            System.out.println("Ad received: " + ad.toString());
        }
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately doesn't work because cannot find `Ad` and `ErrorCode` probably because in latest library have changed something.

How could I fix this?

Comment: have you entered this line `<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"</activity>` in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes, but the error persist

Comment: can you try my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per google admob new api services

**Step**:

1. Download latest Google Play Services library
2. BannerCodeActivity.java

   ```
   public class BannerCodeActivity extends Activity {
       private AdView mAdView;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_banner_code_ad_listener);

           mAdView = new AdView(this);
           mAdView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
           mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
           mAdView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
           RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           layout.addView(mAdView, params);
           mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPause() {
           mAdView.pause();
           super.onPause();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           mAdView.resume();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           mAdView.destroy();
           super.onDestroy();
       }
   }
   ```
3. manifest permission

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   ```

You have to follow all this thing more information from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/).

if any trouble then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean that you are getting a compilation failure.
NB posting an actual error message is always a good idea on StackOverflow.

Check your imports. If you are using the Google Play Services library for Admob then the package has changed to `com.google.android.gms.ads`

The interface for com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener is

```
public abstract class AdListener {
  public void onAdLoaded();
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode);
  public void onAdOpened();
  public void onAdClosed();
  public void onAdLeftApplication();
}
```

NB this has **changed** since Admob-6.4.1
You appear to be using the AdListener from Admob-6.4.1

Comment: I use latest google-play-services.jar and the import are `import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;` but unfortunately the object `Ad` seems missing

Comment: You appear to be using the AdListener from Admob-6.4.1. You need to be using the new AdListener which does not reference Ad or ErrorCode. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can you give me more details? How to print the error using the `onAdFailedToLoad()` and the new API that have no `Ad` object?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate. The error code is one of 4 errors defined there. Ad never really was relevant and was pulled.

Comment: ok, but is unclear how to get the Ad info in my class since doesn't return anything and have no ad object where I can get the info with a toString. could you give me a sample? thanks

Comment: There **is** no Ad object anymore. I suggest you review your use case. Why do you need it?

Comment: @AndreaF  Please review Google Play Services Migration for AdMob (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).  Then you will understand what people are talking about here when they're trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything you need to know how to migrate to the new API is in [this Google Play Services Migration document](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).

One thing it doesn't mention though, are the error codes values (that now are int values) for the new `onAdFailedToLoad` function that replaces the old `onFailedToReceiveAd`.
These are described in [the `AdListener` reference page](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdFailedToLoad%28int%29) and in [the `AdRequest` reference page](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow step by step procedure on [Google Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?csw=1#android). I followed the same and successfully view Adds on Emulator and real device. Also you should add the following line of code in your `Manifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
```

You can also download the sample code from [this Link](http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/Android_Fundamentals.zip)

Comment: Zubair Ahmad Khan hmm.mm

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, this error is because google play service library is not completely added to your project, Right click on the error and select fix project or go to project -> properties -> click on java Build Paths then go to projects and click on Add button s